# Can't Log into MySQL using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed IIS7, MySQL 5.5 and PHP 5.3 on my desktop running Windows 7 Ult 64-bit to develop a website and in order to test *.php webpages locally without having to upload them to my web host.
Everything has been running fine for several months until recently. When I try to log into MySQL database using phpmyadmin the webpage just clears the username and password and stays at the log in page. Even when I enter an incorrect username and password it doesn't say the log in credentials are wrong, it just stays at the log in page. Not even my root username and password will work.

I tried doing a manual password reset as explained on other forums but that didn't get me passed the log in page.

My database is only a test database so I even went as far as uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL. This installed the newer version of MySQL 5.6. That didn't work.

I tried different versions of phpmyadmin from 5.2 thru the newest version 5.7. I changed PHP in IIS7 to PHP 5.4 but that didn't get my log in to work either.

All webpages in *.php open fine on the localhost machine. I can view them fine. I run home server and when I access the website from a remote computer I can navigate the entire website. When I go to http://[remotecomputername]/phpmyadmin and try to log in it just goes to a blank page and doesn't show me the phpmyadmin gui.

Not sure why the log in on the localhost stop working but any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you flush the mysql grant tables?

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong but I'd recommend you using EasyPHP which configures PHP, MySQL and Apache for you in a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0):

go to control panel > administrative  tool> service >

then you will find a list of item , navigate to MYSQL

right click on it > properties  > in general tab > start type ( make it automatic )

then apply / save

and finally restart all services in wamp